# Livewire all requests 404

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I was using the Livewire package on my local machine Ubuntu.20 with Apach2 server and MySQL and Laravelv7, so my problem is when I touch anything on my data table is giving me this error `http://localhost/public/message/customer-list` not found `404`.

this apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/spread-pc



    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


    Alias /spread "/var/www/html/spread-pc"
        <Directory "/var/www/html/spread-pc">
                options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        RewriteEngine On
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all                                
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

config livewire.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Namespace
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value sets the root namespace for Livewire component classes in
    | your application. This value affects component auto-discovery and
    | any Livewire file helper commands, like `artisan make:livewire`.
    |
    | After changing this item, run: `php artisan livewire:discover`.
    |
    */

    'class_namespace' => 'App\\Http\\Livewire',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | View Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value sets the path for Livewire component views. This affects
    | file manipulation helper commands like `artisan make:livewire`.
    |
    */

    'view_path' => resource_path('views/livewire'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Layout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | The default layout view that will be used when rendering a component via
    | Route::get('/some-endpoint', SomeComponent::class);. In this case the
    | the view returned by SomeComponent will be wrapped in "layouts.app"
    |
    */

    'layout' => 'layouts.app',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Livewire Assets URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value sets the path to Livewire JavaScript assets, for cases where
    | your app's domain root is not the correct path. By default, Livewire
    | will load its JavaScript assets from the app's "relative root".
    |
    | Examples: "/assets", "myurl.com/app".
    |
    */

    'asset_url' => 'http://localhost',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Livewire Endpoint Middleware Group
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value sets the middleware group that will be applied to the main
    | Livewire "message" endpoint (the endpoint that gets hit everytime
    | a Livewire component updates). It is set to "web" by default.
    |
    */

    'middleware_group' => 'web',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Livewire Temporary File Uploads Endpoint Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Livewire handles file uploads by storing uploads in a temporary directory
    | before the file is validated and stored permanently. All file uploads
    | are directed to a global endpoint for temporary storage. The config
    | items below are used for customizing the way the endpoint works.
    |
    */

    'temporary_file_upload' => [
        'disk' => null,        // Example: 'local', 's3'              Default: 'default'
        'rules' => null,       // Example: ['file', 'mimes:png,jpg']  Default: ['required', 'file', 'max:12288'] (12MB)
        'directory' => null,   // Example: 'tmp'                      Default  'livewire-tmp'
        'middleware' => null,  // Example: 'throttle:5,1'             Default: 'throttle:60,1'
        'preview_mimes' => [   // Supported file types for temporary pre-signed file URLs.
            'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'svg', 'wav', 'mp4',
            'mov', 'avi', 'wmv', 'mp3', 'm4a',
            'jpg', 'jpeg', 'mpga', 'webp', 'wma',
        ],
        'max_upload_time' => 5, // Max duration (in minutes) before an upload gets invalidated.
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Manifest File Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value sets the path to the Livewire manifest file.
    | The default should work for most cases (which is
    | "<app_root>/bootstrap/cache/livewire-components.php)", but for specific
    | cases like when hosting on Laravel Vapor, it could be set to a different value.
    |
    | Example: for Laravel Vapor, it would be "/tmp/storage/bootstrap/cache/livewire-components.php".
    |
    */

    'manifest_path' => null,

];
```

I tried to change `asset_url => /public`, `asset_url => http://localhost/public`
most of suggested options I used but still same error.
and when I open veiw source `src="/public/vendor/livewire/livewire.js?id=83b555bb3e243bc25f35"` it has data that mean livewire is loading correctly.

some sugessted solution it was to change `mode_rewrite` apache and I did and says `already rewrite`

So I wonder what is wrong with me, I'll be appreciated if someone helps me

Comment: The DocumentRoot of your server should point to the `public/` folder in your project. Adjust `<Directory...` accordingly

Comment: thanks for the reply, but my index.php it's on the root Larave is not inside public folder

Comment: So no vanilla Laravel/Livewire installation?! What did you change? The default is to set the DocumentRoot to the `public` folder, so no files outside of the folder are exposed to the public. Why did you change that? There's an `index.php` inside the `public` folder that serves as entrypoint

Comment: On a sidenote, if you use `php artisan serve` to serve your app, there will be no `public` folder in the URL. Does the site work if you use `php artisan serve`?

Comment: No, I am not using

Comment: Thanks, @brombeer, I change the apache server point to the public and everything now is working fin.